# Am I allowed to treat HCRYPTPROV returned by CryptAcquireContext as a singleton?

Tags: c++, winapi, cryptography, cryptoapi

Is it acceptable that I cache `HCRYPTPROV` returned by [CryptAcquireContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379886(v=vs.85).aspx) when my app starts and reuse it for later cryptographic calls (i.e. calculating HMACs and encrypting/AES) in a form as such:

```
HCRYPTPROV global_hProvSingleton = NULL;

HCRYPTPROV getCryptoContextSingleton()
{
    if(!global_hProvSingleton)
    {
        //Do it only once
        ::CryptAcquireContext(&global_hProvSingleton, NULL, MS_ENH_RSA_AES_PROV, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT | CRYPT_NEWKEYSET);
    }

    return global_hProvSingleton;
}
```

Comment: What are you worried about in particular?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Is it cryptographically secure?